# Akka.net VS Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, .net, akka.net

I am learning about Akka.net and have heard about service fabric from Azure. As far as I know, they both are used for building microservices.

Apart from the difference in the scaling model, what else can be the difference between Akka.net and Azure Service fabric.

I see that the conclusion mentioned in the [following blog](http://mikhail.io/2016/02/akka-net-style-actors-in-service-fabric/) gives hint to using Akka.net with persistent storage from Azure.

Can the real-time implementation developer's share their experiences in these technologies.

I find many use cases that can be solved, but one simple one would be a user import process, which typically contains the following steps,

1. Create user,
2. Add roles to user
3. Send welcome email to the new user
4. Manage user based metering for the company to which the user is being added to.

I see that all the above steps qualified to contain an actor on its own to perform the activities. Kindly comment on the approach that I have understood.

Comment: From developer comfort perspective, service fabric actors are rubbish compared to akka.net. First, documentation and help with errors with service fabric is nearly nonexistent. Secondly, you have to have incredible amounts of boilerplate when compared with Akka.net in order to have just two actor types.

Comment: I assume that service fabric is a way to manage the PAAS aspects of service fabric, and is easy to use Azure messaging infrastructure. I would still like to know if there are production apps and get their feedback compared to Akka.Net

Comment: Service Fabric is Microsoft offering for PaaS in building microservices.  That said, company support, developer community, available resources for Q&A and sample codes are plentiful and will be important for the life of the application.

Comment: Azure SQL DB, Microsoft Teams and Cortana are production workloads on Service Fabric.